# Mutate with a list column function in dplyr

Tags: r, text, dplyr

I am trying to calculate the Jaccard similarity between a source vector and comparison vectors in a tibble.

First, create a tibble with a names_ field (vector of strings).  Using dplyr's mutate, create names_vec, a list-column, where each row is now a vector (each element of vector is a letter).

Then, create a new tibble with column jaccard_sim that is supposed to calculate the Jaccard similarity.

```
source_vec <- c('a', 'b', 'c')

df_comp <- tibble(names_ = c("b d f", "u k g", "m o c"),
              names_vec = strsplit(names_, ' '))

df_comp_jaccard <- df_comp %>%
   dplyr::mutate(jaccard_sim = length(intersect(names_vec, source_vec))/length(union(names_vec, source_vec)))
```

All the values in jaccard_sim are zero.  However, if we run something like this, we get the correct Jaccard similarity of 0.2 for the first entry:

```
a <- length(intersect(source_vec, df_comp[[1,2]]))
b <- length(union(source_vec, df_comp[[1,2]]))
a/b
```

Comment: source_vec is static and is not being iterated over, so I don't see why map2 is required

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could simply add `rowwise`

```
df_comp_jaccard <- df_comp %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(jaccard_sim = length(intersect(names_vec, source_vec))/
                              length(union(names_vec, source_vec)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  names_ names_vec jaccard_sim
   <chr>    <list>       <dbl>
1  b d f <chr [3]>         0.2
2  u k g <chr [3]>         0.0
3  m o c <chr [3]>         0.2
```

Using `rowwise` you get the intuitive behavior some would expect when using `mutate` : "do this operation for every row".

Not using `rowwise` means you take advantage of vectorized functions, which is much faster, that's why it's the default, but may yield unexpected results if you're not careful.

The impression that `mutate` (or other `dplyr` functions) works row-wise is an illusion due to the fact you're working with vectorized functions, in fact you're always juggling with full columns.

I'll illustrate with a couple of examples:

Sometimes the result is the same, with a vectorized function such as `paste`:

```
tibble(a=1:10,b=10:1) %>% mutate(X = paste(a,b,sep="_"))
tibble(a=1:10,b=10:1) %>% rowwise %>% mutate(X = paste(a,b,sep="_"))
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#       a     b     X
#   <int> <int> <chr>
# 1     1     5   1_5
# 2     2     4   2_4
# 3     3     3   3_3
# 4     4     2   4_2
# 5     5     1   5_1
```

And sometimes it's different, with a function that is not vectorized, such as `max`:

```
tibble(a=1:5,b=5:1) %>% mutate(max(a,b))
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#       a     b `max(a, b)`
#   <int> <int>       <int>
# 1     1     5           5
# 2     2     4           5
# 3     3     3           5
# 4     4     2           5
# 5     5     1           5

tibble(a=1:5,b=5:1) %>% rowwise %>% mutate(max(a,b))
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#       a     b `max(a, b)`
#   <int> <int>       <int>
# 1     1     5           5
# 2     2     4           4
# 3     3     3           3
# 4     4     2           4
# 5     5     1           5
```

Note that in this case you shouldn't use `rowwise` in a real life situation, but `pmax` which is vectorized for this purpose:

```
tibble(a=1:5,b=5:1) %>% mutate(pmax(a,b))
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#       a     b `pmax(a, b)`
#   <int> <int>        <int>
# 1     1     5            5
# 2     2     4            4
# 3     3     3            3
# 4     4     2            4
# 5     5     1            5
```

Intersect is such function, you fed this function one list column containing vectors and one other vector, these 2 objects have no intersection.

Comment: Conceptual clarification.  Why does rowwise() become mandatory when we work with list-columns?  This is in contrast with a regular df, where we are free to create new variables with mutate by taking linear combinations of different columns without having to relying on rowwise.

Comment: `rowwise` is never mandatory, you can use `mutate` with `map` as @akrun did in his solution, or `pmap` in other cases, and this is actually the "official recommended solution". `rowwise` is arguably more readable sometimes (less embedded code), though it's more "magical" (few actually understand what it does to your object) and slower. Sorry for the late answer!

Answer (score 12):

We can use `map` to loop through the `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
df_comp %>% 
     mutate(jaccard_sim = map_dbl(names_vec, ~length(intersect(.x, 
                 source_vec))/length(union(.x, source_vec))))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   names_ names_vec jaccard_sim
#    <chr>    <list>       <dbl>
#1  b d f <chr [3]>         0.2
#2  u k g <chr [3]>         0.0
#3  m o c <chr [3]>         0.2
```

---

The `map` functions are optimized.  Below are the `system.time` for a slightly bigger dataset

```
df_comp1 <- df_comp[rep(1:nrow(df_comp), 1e5),]
system.time({

 df_comp1 %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      dplyr::mutate(jaccard_sim = length(intersect(names_vec, source_vec))/length(union(names_vec, source_vec)))
    })
 #user  system elapsed 
 # 25.59    0.05   25.96 

system.time({
  df_comp1 %>% 
     mutate(jaccard_sim = map_dbl(names_vec, ~length(intersect(.x, 
                 source_vec))/length(union(.x, source_vec))))
   })
#user  system elapsed 
#  13.22    0.00   13.22
```