# Compute Jaccard similarity index two columns in dataframe dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with two columns and I want to compute Jaccard's similarity index by row between these two columns (`address` and `gmap_var`):

Here is what I have tried (based on this contribution [Mutate with a list column function in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46886407/mutate-with-a-list-column-function-in-dplyr)). It returns jaccard_sim = 0.

```
example <- example %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(jaccard_sim = length(intersect(address, gmap_var))/length(union(address, gmap_var)))
```

Example data frame:

```
structure(list(address = c("AVENUE DES AVIATEURS, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"MPIKA, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", "H775+677, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"H7QQ+VX8, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", "AVE DE KATO, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"J974+373, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", "COMMUNE DE KIMBANSEKE QUARTIER 17, MAIN, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"COMMUNE DE KIMBANSEKE QUARTIER 17, MAIN, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"AVE DE LA SCIENCE, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"10 NSELE, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", "J974+373, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"J85X+J4W, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", "39HM+RFQ, MUANDA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"FMPM+M22, KWILU NGONGO, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", "QV6F+HGW, MBANZA-NGUNGU, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"QV6F+HGW, MBANZA-NGUNGU, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"QV46+X55, MBANZA-NGUNGU, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"QV6F+HGW, MBANZA-NGUNGU, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"UNNAMED ROAD, SONGOLOLO, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"AV. MOBUTU, INKISI, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", "QV46+X55, MBANZA-NGUNGU, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"M8R8+9W2, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", "NGILIMA II, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO", 
"M8R8+9W2, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO"), gmap_var = c("PAROISE ST ANNE, GOMBE, KINSHASA, CD", 
"AVENUE MOSSAMBA, 116, NGIRI-NGIRI, KINSHASA, CD", "6E ET 7EME RUE CITE VERTE/PAROISSE ST., SELEMBAO, KINSHASA, CD", 
"ROUTE MATADIPAROISSE MATERDEI, MONT-NGAFULA, KINSHASA, CD", 
"AVENUE MARINE, 362, NGALIEMA, KINSHASA, CD", "AVENUE DU MARCHE NO. 46 PAROISSE ST. THOMAS, KIMBANSEKE, KINSHASA, CD", 
"AVENUE LINGOMO, NO 123/124, KIMBANSEKE, KINSHASA, CD", "24,LINGOMO Q/ NGAMAYAMA, KIMBANSEKE, KINSHASA, CD", 
"CENTRE MISSIONNAIRE BUSIRA DIMI, NON LOIN DU, MALUKU, KINSHASA, CD", 
"AVENUE MBIMI NO 10, NSELE, KINSHASA, CD", "PAROISSE ST AMBROISE, 1. Q. KABILA, KISENSO, KINSHASA, CD", 
"LOC. KINZAZI/PAROISSE ST ALPHONSE, MATETE, KINSHASA, CD", "PAROISSE KIMBANGUISTE, LUKULA, CONGO CENTRAL, CD", 
"PAROISSE NOTRES DAME, KWILU-NGONGO, CONGO CENTRAL, CD", "PAROISSE SAINTE MARIE DE LOMA, MBANZA-NGUNGU, CONGO CENTRAL, CD", 
"PAROISSE CATHOLIQUE STE THERESE, MBANZA-NGUNGU, CONGO CENTRAL, CD", 
"PAROISSE CATHOLIQUE CHRIST ROI, MBANZA-NGUNGU, CONGO CENTRAL, CD", 
"PAROISSE NKAMBA, NTIMANSI, CONGO CENTRAL, CD", "PAROISSE CATHOLIQUE SONGOLOLO, SONGOLOLO, CONGO CENTRAL, CD", 
"PAROISSE ST JOSEPH, INKISI, CONGO CENTRAL, CD", "PAROISSE STE FAMILLE, INKISI, CONGO CENTRAL, CD", 
"PAROISSE ARMEE DU SALUT, INKISI, CONGO CENTRAL, CD", "PAROISSE CEC KILOMBO, INKISI, CONGO CENTRAL, CD", 
"PAROISSE ARMEE DU SALUT, KASANGULU, CONGO CENTRAL, CD")), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split the sentences into words and then you can use the formula from the other post.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~strsplit(., ',?\\s*'), .names = '{col}_vec')) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(jaccard_sim = length(intersect(address_vec, gmap_var_vec))/
                       length(union(address_vec, gmap_var_vec)))

#  address                     gmap_var                 address_vec gmap_var_vec jaccard_sim
#   <chr>                       <chr>                    <list>      <list>             <dbl>
# 1 AVENUE DES AVIATEURS, KINS… PAROISE ST ANNE, GOMBE,… <chr [62]>  <chr [33]>         0.810
# 2 MPIKA, KINSHASA, DEMOCRATI… AVENUE MOSSAMBA, 116, N… <chr [47]>  <chr [43]>         0.667
# 3 H775+677, KINSHASA, DEMOCR… 6E ET 7EME RUE CITE VER… <chr [50]>  <chr [59]>         0.741
# 4 H7QQ+VX8, KINSHASA, DEMOCR… ROUTE MATADIPAROISSE MA… <chr [50]>  <chr [54]>         0.704
# 5 AVE DE KATO, KINSHASA, DEM… AVENUE MARINE, 362, NGA… <chr [53]>  <chr [38]>         0.667
# 6 J974+373, KINSHASA, DEMOCR… AVENUE DU MARCHE NO. 46… <chr [50]>  <chr [66]>         0.621
# 7 COMMUNE DE KIMBANSEKE QUAR… AVENUE LINGOMO, NO 123/… <chr [80]>  <chr [48]>         0.607
# 8 COMMUNE DE KIMBANSEKE QUAR… 24,LINGOMO Q/ NGAMAYAMA… <chr [80]>  <chr [46]>         0.593
# 9 AVE DE LA SCIENCE, KINSHAS… CENTRE MISSIONNAIRE BUS… <chr [59]>  <chr [62]>         0.810
#10 10 NSELE, KINSHASA, DEMOCR… AVENUE MBIMI NO 10, NSE… <chr [50]>  <chr [36]>         0.739
# … with 14 more rows
```